# I want to do is to be able to click to stop while keeping the image and sound behavior even if I go to another link and return to LP again

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently creating a homepage
The LP has several images arranged, and when you click on those images, the images move and make a sound (it's looping), and there are other links such as BIO, Music, Contactn, etc.
Click the image again to stop the movement and sound.

but when I go to another link and return to LP in that state, the image stop the still state (State before clicking), and the sound keep working but you can't do stop. If you want do stop, you have to do relord. (The loop sound keeps looping while you are on another link)

What I want to do is to be able to click to stop while keeping the image and sound behavior even if I go to another link and return to LP again.

I would appreciate it if you could teach me.
Thank you.

[enter link description here](https://github.com/yusuke85/kazumi_hp)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap"

import Boat from "../Images/Boat.jpeg"
import Bus from "../Images/Bus.jpeg"
import Grass from "../Images/Grass.jpeg"
import Macba01 from "../Images/Macba01.JPG"
import Metro from "../Images/Metro.jpeg"
import MorningSun from "../Images/MorningSun.jpeg"
import Pingpong from "../Images/Pingpong.jpeg"
import Bell from "../Images/Bell.jpeg"
import Blank from "../Images/Blank-0001.jpg"

import FuneAudio from "../Audio/Boat.mp3"
import InsideMetro from "../Audio/OnTheMetro.mp3"
import MorningSunAudio from "../Audio/MorningS.mp3"
import BusAudio from "../Audio/Bus.mp3"
import GrassAudio from "../Audio/Grass.mp3"
import MacbaAudio from "../Audio/Macba.mp3"
import BellAudio from "../Audio/new_Bell.mp3"
import PingpongAudio from "../Audio/pingpong.wav"

import "../Styles/LandingPage.css"





const useAudio = () => {
  const [audio] = useState(new Audio(FuneAudio));
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);


  const toggle = () => setPlaying(!playing);


  useEffect(() => {
    playing ? audio.play() : audio.pause();
    audio.loop = true;
  },
    [playing, audio]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    audio.addEventListener('ended', () => setPlaying(false));
    return () => {
      audio.removeEventListener('ended', () => setPlaying(false));
    };
  }, [audio]);

  return [playing, toggle];
};

// -------------------------------------------------//

const useAudio2 = () => {
  const [audio] = useState(new Audio(InsideMetro));
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => setPlaying(!playing);

  useEffect(() => {
    playing ? audio.play() : audio.pause();
    audio.loop = true;
  },
    [playing, audio]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    audio.addEventListener('ended', () => setPlaying(false));
    return () => {
      audio.removeEventListener('ended', () => setPlaying(false));
    };
  }, [audio]);

  return [playing, toggle];
};

// -------------------------------------------------//

const useAudio3 = () => {
  const [audio] = useState(new Audio(MorningSunAudio));
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => setPlaying(!playing);

  useEffect(() => {
    playing ? audio.play() : audio.pause();
    audio.loop = true;
  },
    [playing, audio]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    audio.addEventListener('ended', () => setPlaying(false));
    return () => {
      audio.removeEventListener('ended', () => setPlaying(false));
    };
  }, [audio]);

  return [playing, toggle];
};
// -------------------------------------------------//

const useAudio4 = () => {
  const [audio] = useState(new Audio(BusAudio));
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => setPlaying(!playing);

  useEffect(() => {
    playing ? audio.play() : audio.pause();
    audio.loop = true;
  },
    [playing, audio]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    audio.addEventListener('ended', () => setPlaying(false));
    return () => {
      audio.removeEventListener('ended', () => setPlaying(false));
    };
  }, [audio]);

  return [playing, toggle];
};
// -------------------------------------------------//

const useAudio5 = () => {
  const [audio] = useState(new Audio(GrassAudio));
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => setPlaying(!playing);

  useEffect(() => {
    playing ? audio.play() : audio.pause();
    audio.loop = true;
  },
    [playing, audio]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    audio.addEventListener('ended', () => setPlaying(false));
    return () => {
      audio.removeEventListener('ended', () => setPlaying(false));
    };
  }, [audio]);

  return [playing, toggle];
};
// -------------------------------------------------//

const useAudio6 = () => {
  const [audio] = useState(new Audio(BellAudio));
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => setPlaying(!playing);

  useEffect(() => {
    playing ? audio.play() : audio.pause();
    audio.loop = true;
  },
    [playing, audio]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    audio.addEventListener('ended', () => setPlaying(false));
    return () => {
      audio.removeEventListener('ended', () => setPlaying(false));
    };
  }, [audio]);

  return [playing, toggle];
};
// -------------------------------------------------//

const useAudio7 = () => {
  const [audio] = useState(new Audio(MacbaAudio));
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => setPlaying(!playing);

  useEffect(() => {
    playing ? audio.play() : audio.pause();
    audio.loop = true;
  },
    [playing, audio]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    audio.addEventListener('ended', () => setPlaying(false));
    return () => {
      audio.removeEventListener('ended', () => setPlaying(false));
    };
  }, [audio]);

  return [playing, toggle];
};
// -------------------------------------------------//

const useAudio8 = () => {
  const [audio] = useState(new Audio(PingpongAudio));
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => setPlaying(!playing);

  useEffect(() => {
    playing ? audio.play() : audio.pause();
    audio.loop = true;
  },
    [playing, audio]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    audio.addEventListener('ended', () => setPlaying(false));
    return () => {
      audio.removeEventListener('ended', () => setPlaying(false));
    };
  }, [audio]);

  return [playing, toggle];
};




const LandingPage = () => {

  const [playing, toggle] = useAudio(FuneAudio);
  const [playing2, toggle2] = useAudio2(InsideMetro)
  const [playing3, toggle3] = useAudio3(MorningSunAudio)
  const [playing4, toggle4] = useAudio4(BusAudio)
  const [playing5, toggle5] = useAudio5(GrassAudio)
  const [playing6, toggle6] = useAudio6(BellAudio)
  const [playing7, toggle7] = useAudio7(MacbaAudio)
  const [playing8, toggle8] = useAudio8(PingpongAudio)

  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  const classToggle = () => {
    setActive(!active)
  }
  const [active2, setActive2] = useState(false);
  const classToggle2 = () => {
    setActive2(!active2)
  }
  const [active3, setActive3] = useState(false);
  const classToggle3 = () => {
    setActive3(!active3)
  }
  const [active4, setActive4] = useState(false);
  const classToggle4 = () => {
    setActive4(!active4)
  }
  const [active5, setActive5] = useState(false);
  const classToggle5 = () => {
    setActive5(!active5)
  }
  const [active6, setActive6] = useState(false);
  const classToggle6 = () => {
    setActive6(!active6)
  }
  const [active7, setActive7] = useState(false);
  const classToggle7 = () => {
    setActive7(!active7)
  }
  const [active8, setActive8] = useState(false);
  const classToggle8 = () => {
    setActive8(!active8)
  }


  return (
    <>
      <h2 id="pleaseClick">
        Please click on the images!!
      </h2>
      <Container className="lpPhotos">
        <Row id="item1">
          <Col md={2} sm={2} xs={2}>
            <img src={Blank} id="blank" className="img-fluid" alt="..." />
          </Col>
          <Col md={2} sm={2} xs={2}>
            <img src={Bell} id={active6 ? "bell" : ""} className="img-fluid" alt="..." onClick={() => { toggle6(); classToggle6() }} />{playing6}
          </Col>
          <Col md={2} sm={2} xs={2}>
            <img src={Blank} id="blank" className="img-fluid" alt="..." />
          </Col>
          <Col md={2} sm={2} xs={2}>
            <img src={Boat} id={active ? "boat" : ""} className="img-fluid" alt="..." onClick={() => { toggle(); classToggle() }} />{playing}
          </Col>
          <Col md={2} sm={2} xs={2}>
            <img src={Grass} id={active5 ? "grass" : ""} className="img-fluid" alt="..." onClick={() => { toggle5(); classToggle5() }} />{playing5}
          </Col>
          <Col md={2} sm={2} xs={2}>
            <img src={Pingpong} id={active8 ? "pingpong" : ""} className="img-fluid" alt="..." onClick={() => { toggle8(); classToggle8() }} />{playing8}
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row id="item2">
          <Col md={2} sm={2} xs={2}>
            <img src={Bus} id={active4 ? "bus" : ""} className="img-fluid" alt="..." onClick={() => { toggle4(); classToggle4() }} />{playing4}
          </Col>
          <Col md={2} sm={2} xs={2}>
            <img src={Blank} id="blank" className="img-fluid" alt="..." />
          </Col>
          <Col md={2} sm={2} xs={2}>
            <img src={Macba01} id={active7 ? "macba" : ""} className="img-fluid" alt="..." onClick={() => { toggle7(); classToggle7() }} />{playing7}
          </Col>
          <Col md={2} sm={2} xs={2}>
            <img src={Metro} id={active2 ? "metro" : ""} className="img-fluid" alt="..." onClick={() => { toggle2(); classToggle2() }} />{playing2}
          </Col>
          <Col md={2} sm={2} xs={2}>
            <img src={MorningSun} id={active3 ? "morningSun" : ""} className="img-fluid" alt="..." onClick={() => { toggle3(); classToggle3() }} />{playing3}
          </Col>
          <Col md={2} sm={2} xs={2}>
            <img src={Blank} id="blank" className="img-fluid" alt="..." />
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </>

  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing `audio` from this `useEffects` dependency array like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    audio.addEventListener('ended', () => setPlaying(false));
    return () => {
      audio.removeEventListener('ended', () => setPlaying(false));
    };
  }, []); // <---- remove audio from this dependecy array
```

On a side note, you should look into `array`s in general, as your code is redundant. You keep repeating yourself, instead of `map`ping over an `array` of your mp3s etc.

Comment: Yes, I tried remove audio but it's doesn't changed.